# Jquery :selected selector causes function to return with no error

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've been struggling with a strange problem for the last half an hour. Take a look at this code:

```
var select=$('#models option');
var selectedOption=$('#models option:selected');//function stops execution at this line
//Rest of the code goes here
```

When I reach the line where I say `$('#models option:selected')`, the process just exists the function without any kind of warning or an error. I've been always doing this without any problem. I've tried `('#models :selected')` and still I get the same thing. does anybody have any clue what is going on?

Comment: Code looks OK. Can you reproduce this in stack-snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: There you go https://jsfiddle.net/h7vuhkdf/

Comment: looks like you're trying to get selected option value. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/h7vuhkdf/1/)

Comment: Yes, but I don't even reach to that point. The process exists the function where I try to get the selected option itself.

Comment: the jsfiddle demo is incomplete. it seems like some html elements are missing by seeing the jquery code